# Why ActivePerl does not show all modules available on CPAN in search results

Tags: perl, cpan, activeperl

Why there are some modules which can be only installed from command prompt, they are not listed in search list of modules in ActivePerl.

Comment: Consider using [`Strawberry Perl`](http://strawberryperl.com/) for windows instead of ActivePerl for a more unix style perl experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cpan-faq](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html)

If you're using ActivePerl on Windows, the PPM (Perl Package Manager) has much of the same functionality as CPAN.pm.

---

From Activestate

**Why are some builds missing in PPM?**

> Builds for a package could be missing for various reasons:
>
> If you see the failed icon (FAILED), it means that the build failed on
> that particular platform. You can click on this icon and visit the
> build log to diagnose what went wrong.
>
> If you see the missing icon (MISSING), it means that the package has
> not yet been built and tested by the PPM build server for this
> particular platform.
>
> If you see "n/a" it means there is no PPM repository for this
> platform. Currently there are no 64-bit repositories for Perl 5.8, and
> no 32-bit repository for Perl 5.12 on Solaris.

---

What to do in case the module is missing from PPM?

Use either `cpan ModuleName` or `cpanm ModuleName` to install it.

See: http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_install_Perl_modules

Comment: sorry but what's the functionality of CPAN.pm?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to install Modules which are not available via `PPM`, you can install [`App::cpanminus`](http://p3rl.org/App%3a%3acpanminus), using `ppm install App::cpanminus` and then install the module directly from cpan. using

```
cpanm <MODULNAME>
```